# Cycle single record with Tab key

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get a certain `tab` & `enter` key behaviour in the datagridview. Once the focus is on a cell in the datagridview, I'd like the following:

`TAB` - cycles through cells in the row, without going to the next row after the last cell in the row. I.e. Keep cycling through the cells in an individual row.

`ENTER` - moves to the next row.

I've been looking online for solutions but they're generally not quite the behaviour I'm after, and they mostly require creating a derived `DataGridView` class, which I'd prefer to avoid if possible.

I also want to avoid triggering the `RowLeave` event, because I'm using that to validate & then accept/reject any cell changes made in that row - hence the conscious `ENTER` key press to move away from the row and trigger its validation & persistence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a solution to this now, and thought I should update here with detail of the particular approach I took.

I put in `DataGridView`'s `OnKeyDown` event something along the lines of:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        if (dataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid[1,dataGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex]; 
            }
    }
```

Seems to do the trick.